# Wrapper.instance() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am running a test at the moment and these 2 lines are missing on my coverage

```
hideAddViewModal = () => {
  this.setState({showAddViewModal: false})
}
```

I wrote the following test, but not sure why is not picking up.
Am I missing anything? 
Mounting my component using Enzyme and Jest

```
it ('Test hideAddViewModal method ',() => {
  wrapper.setState({
   showAddViewModal: false,
  });
  wrapper.update();
  expect(wrapper.instance().hideAddViewModal('test')).toEqual()
  expect(wrapper.state('hideAddViewModal')).toBeFalsy();
});
```

> Error:  wrapper.instance(...).hideAddViewModal is not a function

Comment: how are you declaring the `wrapper`?  are you using shallow render or mounting the component with `enzyme`?

Comment: Mount -  with a <BrowserRouter>

Comment: Please include in your question the code that is declaring the `wrapper` and include more information about the component itself. Keep in mind that from React 16 and above, `stateless` components will always return `null`.

Comment: @Jotakun that's all the information that I have in my code. for hideAddviewModal

Comment: Can you post your component code?

Answer (score 2):

From your limited description, you may need to do shallow wrapper.dive() to get into the component you are actually testing. (you may need to dive multiple times depending on whether your component is connected, I can't see from this post).